# CHKDSK at boot time on windows 7 without a reason

Tags: windows-7, windows, smart, chkdsk

My new PC with a fresh windows 7 starts a chkdsk during boot time maybe once a week. The chkdsk always finishes with 0 problems and the computer restarts into windows as normal.

I always shutdown properly this PC and I haven't got any crash that could cause any damage to the filesystem.

I've tried to find some log or event entry to know why the chkdsk starts but I haven't found any.

Is there a log of chkdsk activity?

Could this be that the drive SMART system is finding some problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it is a bug on the NTFS when two processes access the same file. More details at http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/fi-FI/w7itprogeneral/thread/df935a52-a0a9-4f67-ac82-bc39e0585148

The error gets registered on the windows event registry under System/Ntfs.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for such troubles is probably that during shutdown some software turns on the "dirty" bit of the hard disk. This software can be a device driver, but is more often an antivirus (avira is often cited).

The measures that you can take are:

1. Try running for a week without your antivirus and see if the problem disappears (you can make up for this week with a deep antivirus scan later on). If the problem disappears, switch to another antivirus product.
2. Update all your drivers using downloads from the manufacturer's site. After that, ensure that all optional Windows Updates relating to devices are installed.

Comment: Thanks, but there is not any antivirus installed apart from Microsoft Security Essentials.

Comment: @Serhii: No reason that MSE couldn't be the culprit. But see also the second part of my answer. Consider creating a system restore snapshot before monkeying with drivers.

Comment: The drivers are up to date and I've changed the disk 3 days ago. Let's wait to see if it happens again.